# Criar uma pré visualização de um arquivo XML com CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estou criando um sistema de entrada/saída de estoque utilizando um arquivo XML

Para isso, eu preciso de criar uma pré-visualização do conteúdo do XML que o usuário está fazendo o upload (como uma tabela, só para a pessoa saber se é aquele XML mesmo)

Estou desenvolvendo em CodeIgniter, o recebimento do XML pela controller é assim:

```
  public function recebeXML(){
        $arquivo = $_FILES['arquivo'];
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($arquivo['tmp_name']);
        $numProdutos = count(/*numero de produtos*/);
        for($i = 0; $i<$numProdutos; $i++){
            $produto = $xml->NFe->det[$i]->prod;

                $dados[$i] = array(
                    "CodigoProduto" => (string)$produto->cProd,
                    "NomeProduto" => (string)$produto->xProd,
                    "Quantidade" => (string)$produto->uCom,
                );
            }
        }

        $this->entradaDados($dados);
    }
```

Os dados são colocados na tabela por meio de um foreach.

A pergunta em si é : tem como colocar os dados organizados a visão do usuário sem precisar recarregar a página? Eu pensei em criar uma modal para aparecer depois que eu fizesse o upload, mas como colocar os arquivos lá dentro?

Comment: Você queria algo com Ajax, sem dar refresh na pagina? ou seja, esse código já funciona, mas, você quer fazer com uma interação melhor?

Comment: Exatamente isso, eu só não sei como proceder com isso

Comment: Tem que fazer um post com ajax passando o arquivo XML igual você já o faz tradicionalmente e na resposta do ajax resgatar esses dados e mostrar em uma tabela, por exemplo com Angular seria fácil a montagem disso, mas, são passos a serem seguidos.

Comment: Você tem noção de algum site ou fórum que detalhe mais como fazer isso? Eu não sei absolutamente nada sobre AJAX

Comment: Aqui no site tem bastante link sobre ajax (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajax) é só dar uma lida, eu até posso montar um exemplo minimo quem sabe se pode usar como exemplo e passar isso para o seu código.

Comment: Pode ser, ajudaria bastante!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicamente o seu código pode ser reaproveitado porque, já gera as informações, mas, vou propor um simples exemplo mediante a um [xml](/questions/tagged/xml) com [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax):

***Organização de Pastas***

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***XML***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Items>
    <Item>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>São Paulo</name>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>Rio de Janeiro</name>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <id>3</id>
        <name>Osasco</name>
    </Item>
</Items>
```

`View`

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
    <h1>Home</h1>
    <div>
        <input type="file" name="arquivo" id="arquivo">
    </div>
    <button id="btnCarregar">Carregar</button>
    <table id="tbl">        
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
    <script src="/public/js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function myDataForm()
        {
            var fdata = new FormData();
            fdata.append('arquivo', $('#arquivo')[0].files[0]);
            return fdata;
        }
        function call_tabela(result)
        {
            var tbody = $("#tbl tbody");
            tbody.empty();
            $.each(result, function(index, item){
                tbody.append('<tr>')
                tbody.append('<td>'+item.id+'</td>');
                tbody.append('<td>'+item.name+'</td>');
                tbody.append('<tr>');
            });         
        }
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#btnCarregar").click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/home/receive',
                    type: 'POST',
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: myDataForm(),
                    success: function(result) 
                    {                       
                        call_tabela(result.Item);
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) 
                    {
                        console.log(xhr);
                    }
                });         
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

`Controller`

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller 
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('home');
    }

    public function receive()
    {
        $values = simplexml_load_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name']);
        echo json_encode($values);
    }
}
```

Basicamente esse código faz a escolha de um xml de sua preferencia no meu caso eu coloquei um exemplo na própria resposta e esse é o exemplo e a tela inicial:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

após mostrar o arquivo e mandar carregar a tela inicial carrega os dados sem `refresh`:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito bom! vou tentar utilizar

Comment: Se for útil @WalterFelipe aceite como resposta!

Comment: vou fazer isso, eu só tenho uma duvida no call_tabela() 
você podia me explicar o que faz ali?

Comment: @WalterFelipe crie o Rows que vem do PHP! ou seja as tr e td na tbody daquela tabela!

Comment: ele está dando erro no diretório de pasta da controller... pode me passar a sua organização de pasta? só para eu ter uma noção

Comment: @WalterFelipe está na resposta editada. Qual é o erro?

Comment: Já foi resolvido, eu coloquei da forma que escreveu na resposta e funcionou perfeitamente